# logical OR bitwise OR interchangeable?

Tags: c, arduino, bit-manipulation

Say I have 2 comparison

```
if ((length >= 524288) | (length == 0))
{
      //do something...
}
```

vs

```
if ((length >= 524288) || (length == 0))
{
      //do something...
}
```

are these the same thing since when you bitwise OR 0001 0000 it turns into 1?
Also is there any particular reason to use bitwise OR in this situation?

Comment: No. `if (p == NULL || p->n > 10)` is OK, but `if ((p == NULL) |  (p->n > 10))` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AndrewL. That answer is for C# is that the same as C?

Comment: They are the same exact operators and these operators are universal in their operation

Comment: @KerrekSB Is there any particular reason to use | in this situation?  I am trying to read through a piece of arduino code and I have no idea why the author used bitwise OR.

Comment: @bakalolo: No. Never underestimate the likelihood of seeing bad code in the wild.

Comment: You would use bitwise or for branchless code or in this case to minimize the number of branches... To help with branch prediction, help the compiler vectorize or prevent timing attacks ... Micro-optimizations basically.

Answer (score 2):

In that case bitwise = logical since both tests return 0 or 1.

The only difference with single `|` is that both parts of the test will be executed whatever the result of the first test => use `||` here.

Comment: As in short-circuit evaluation of compound boolean expressions. So there is a diiference if the second part has a side-effect.

Comment: and If you are reading from a hardware register that can be safely read, say, once every 100 milliseconds, it could trigger a bug.